# SELECT WHERE (column name is a result of another query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables;

`dbo.Users`:

```
user_id user_name   gender   has_phone
--------------------------------------
1       admin       Male     true
2       UserA       Male     false
3       UserB       Female   true
```

and `dbo.Filterby`:

```
id  name        filterid    filtervalue 
---------------------------------------
1   All         NULL        -1              
2   Males       gender      Male            
3   Females     gender      Female  
4   Phone       has_phone   true
5   NoPhone     has_phone   false
```

I need to select all patients based on the result of the query from the filterby, so for example I want all males returned:

```
SELECT 
    [user_id], [user_name] 
FROM 
    dbo.Users
WHERE 
    (SELECT filterid FROM dbo.Filterby WHERE id = 2) = (SELECT filtervalue FROM dbo.Filterby WHERE id = 2)
```

This should be more generic, so I can pass in any Filterby.id and it will return the correct results. But basically, I really just need to know how to select using a result from another query as the column identifier.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is completely independent from dbo.Users... It's either always TRUE or always FALSE, i.e. you will all rows from dbo.Users or none.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: Indeed - either dynamic or some humongous and impossible to maintain case logic.... so, go with dynamic SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirement is for this, but there is probably a better way to do it...

Comment: Using dynamic query is fine but if you do not want to this, there are ways to redesign the stored procedure(if you can use one) and achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    user_id, user_name, gender, has_phone 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        u.user_id,u.user_name, u.gender,u.has_phone, 
        CASE ISNULL(f.filterid,'')
            WHEN '' THEN '-1'
            WHEN 'gender' THEN u.gender
            WHEN 'has_phone' THEN u.has_phone
        END AS val,
        f.filtervalue
    FROM users AS u
        CROSS JOIN Filterby AS f
    WHERE f.id=4  -- here id of filter
) AS m
WHERE
    val=filtervalue
```

In the case where you need to use filtration by two or more fields for example this filtration table

```
id  name        filterid    filtervalue 
---------------------------------------
1   All         NULL        -1              
2   Males       gender      Male            
3   Females     gender      Female  
4   PhoneMales  has_phone   true
4   PhoneMales  gender      Male
5   NoPhone     has_phone   false
```

Then you could use enchanted version of query

```
SELECT 
    m2.user_id, u2.user_name, u2.gender, u2.has_phone
FROM (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM (  
        SELECT
            u.user_id, 
            CASE ISNULL(f.filterid,'')
                WHEN '' THEN '-1'
                WHEN 'gender' THEN u.gender
                WHEN 'has_phone' THEN u.has_phone
            END AS val,
            f.filtervalue
        FROM users AS u
            CROSS JOIN Filterby AS f
        WHERE f.id=4  -- here id of filter
    ) AS m
    WHERE val=filtervalue 
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*)=(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Filterby WHERE id=4 -- here must be the same filter id as above 
    )
) AS m2 
    INNER JOIN users AS u2
      ON m2.user_id=u2.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using dynamic SQL is going to be the simplest way to do this. Take a look at the example below. Basically I think you would want to split this up using a variable and then some dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @Table_Name VARCHAR(1000) /*Would actually be an input parameter in  
our SP.*/

DECLARE @Statement VARCHAR(1000) /*Declaration of our SQL statement to 

execute.*/

SET @Table_Name = 'ErrorLog' /*The value for our input parameter*/

SET @Statement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + '[dbo].[' + @Table_Name + ']'; 

/*Dynamically creating the SQL statement with our table_name variable.*/

EXEC (@Statement); /*We execute the @statement to get our results.*/
```

The above takes a declared variable and then executes a statement based on that. Depending on your needs you could just also use a variable. You might also look at doing this in a stored procedure where your passing in your filtervalue.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @a nvarchar(30)

declare @table table (a nvarchar(30))

insert into @table values('select ''''''a''''''')

select @a=a from @table

exec(@a)
```

In fourth line  you are storing --> SELECT 'a'  into variable @a
and in fifth line you are executing @a

In this you are assigning data in onte table to some variable and executing that data using exec() command.

---

Please mark this as answer or vote this if it helps you